# Random String Generator (PHP)

Tags: php, random

I am trying write a PHP function that returns a random string of a given length. I wrote this:

```
<?
function generate_string($lenght) {
    $ret = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $lenght; $i++) {
        $ret .= chr(mt_rand(32,126));
    }
    return $ret;
}

echo generate_string(150);
?>
```

The above function generates a random string, but the length of the string is not constant, ie: one time it is 30 characters, the other is 60 (obviously I call it with the same length as input every time). I've searched other examples of random string generators, but they all use a base string to pick letters. I am wondering why this method is not working properly.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your function call look like?

Comment: Show us the code that is calling the function (including the lines before and after the call). BTW, length is spelled incorrectly (not that PHP cares.)

Comment: Also, minor quibble: it's "length" and not "lenght" - maybe you're confusing this somewhere?

Comment: <?
 
    function generate_string($lenght)
    {
        $ret = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $lenght; $i++) 
        {
            $ret .= chr(mt_rand(32,126));
        }
        return $ret;
    }

echo generate_string(150);
?>

Comment: @Komut, please put it into your post, not on a comment...and you're passing a length of 150?

Comment: i did as i saw the code is not showing well in the comment =)

Comment: Why are you passing a length of 150?

Comment: that is strange.. you can see here http://codepad.org/7OE4PUMi that the length is constant between calls and it is the one provided.. what are you checking when you say that the number of chars changes? if you output the results to the browser some entities might be formed from some consecutive characters..

Comment: offtopic: you should avoid short open tags http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Code looks fine to me. I can only deduce that either you're not passing it the value you think you are, or that you're calling it twice and viewing the output in a manner that makes it looks like one call (like not printing a line break between them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Educated guess: you attempt to display your plain text string as HTML. The browser, after being told it's HTML, handles it as such. As soon as a `<` character is generated, the following characters are rendered as an (unknown) HTML tag and are not displayed as HTML standards mandate.

Fix:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(generate_string(150));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the conclusion i reached after testing it a while : Your functions works correctly. It depends on what you do with the randomly generated string. If you are simply echo-ing it, then it might generate somthing like `<ck1ask` which will be treated like a tag. Try eliminating certain characters from being concatenated to the string.

Answer (score 0):

This function will work to generate a random string in PHP

```
function getRandomString($maxlength=12, $isSpecialChar=false)
{
    $randomString=null;
   //initalise the string include lower case, upper case and numbers
   $charSet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

   //if required special character to include, please set $isSpecialchar= 1 or true
  if ($isSpecialChar) $charSet .= "~@#$%^*()_±={}|][";

  //loop for get specify length character with random characters
  for ($i=0; $i<$maxlength; $i++) $randomString .= $charSet[(mt_rand(0,   (strlen($charSet)-1)))];

   //return the random string
   return $randomString;
}
//call the function set value you required to string length default:12
$random8char=getRandomString(8);
echo $random8char;
```

Source: [Generate random string in php](https://rameshkotkar.com/programming-languages/php/generate-random-string-php)